# How to fix error 403 when making a post request to Jenkins use Python requests library?

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-api

I want to delete a job in Jenkins use api, I use python's requests library.

It ok when I make a GET request (requests.get(...)) but when I make a POST request (requests.post(...)), it return code 403.

I searched a solution use urllib2, but I can't find it on my library (have urllib, urllib3 but not urllib2).

Does anyone know what my problem is and how to fix it?

I use Python 3.7.3 and Jenkins version 2.176.1

```py
import requests

if __name__ == "__main__":

    server = 'my jenkins server'
    username = 'my user'
    passwd = 'my password'

    params = {}
    job = 'Test_2'
    api = '/doDelete'
    url = server + '/job/' + job + api
    response = requests.post(url=url, auth=(username, passwd), params=params)

    print(response.status_code)
```

Output is '403'

Comment: Did you try check request with `curl`? Also, check your username/password.

Comment: Yes, I did. My username/password had no problem because I use them for get request and it work.

Comment: Do you get more information when printing the content of your response? `print(response.content)`.